# How to change its own button image on tap in Swift

Tags: swift

Now i have an button with an image,
I wanted to change the button image when I tap the button.
How to change its own button image on tap in Swift

do i need to add an outlet?

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnSmiley: UIButton!

@IBAction func btnSmiley(sender: AnyObject) {
    btnSmiley.image = UIImage(named: "smiley")
}
```

Comment: Is the button then selected, so it toggles on and off? Or just change it and leave it? You don't really need an outlet, you get passed the sender.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320597/swift-how-can-i-make-an-image-change-when-a-button-its-pressed-and-return-it/28320648#28320648

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this

```
@IBAction func btnSmiley(sender: UIButton) {
    if let image = UIImage(named:"smiley") {
        sender.setImage(image, forControlState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you toggle this?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```swift
    var check = true

    @IBOutlet weak var btnSmiley: UIButton!

    @IBAction func btnSmiley(sender: AnyObject) {

        check = !check

        if check == true {
            btnSmiley.setImage(UIImage(named: "red"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            btnSmiley.setImage(UIImage(named: "blue"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
@IBAction func btnSmiley(sender: AnyObject) {
    btnSmiley .setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
}
```