# Update UIButton image using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

When I try using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343289/how-to-change-its-own-button-image-on-tap-in-swift) to update an UIButton image (Xcode 7 beta 1), it gives me this error

> Cannot invoke 'setImage' with an argument list of type '(UIImage?, forState: nil)'

Here's the code:

```
if counter % 2 == 0{
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), forState: nil)
}
else if counter % 2 == 1 {
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: nil)
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `forState` argument cannot be `nil` - It has to be a [`UIControlState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

In your case, you should use `UIControlState.Normal`

```
if counter % 2 == 0{
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
else if counter % 2 == 1 {
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can replace UIControlState.Normal with .Normal (Both will work Fine Better to use .Normal because this will be swift short hand feature)

```
if counter % 2 == 0{
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause"), forState: .Normal)
}
else if counter % 2 == 1 {
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), forState: .Normal)
}
```